# Working out how Yii2 finds theme resources when using fallbacks

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am using `Yii2` and have been reading about [theming](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-theming.html) and [theme inheritance](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-theming.html#theme-inheritance); however have some questions:

Consider the following example:

```
'view' => [
    'theme' => [
        'pathMap' => [
            '@app/views' => [
                '@app/themes/current',
                '@app/themes/default',
            ],
        ],
        'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/current',
        'basePath' => '@webroot/themes/current',
    ],
],
```

Now, imagine we request the theme file `foo`; as I understand it this will first be looked for in the following order:

- `@app/themes/current/foo.php`
- `@app/themes/default/foo.php`
- `@app/views/foo.php`

Now imagine `foo.php` isn't found in the `@app/themes/current/` theme, so it would use the file found in `@app/themes/default/`.

Now, considering the `baseUrl` and `basePath` settings I am a little confused how these are used in these situations.

Now, imagine `foo.php` references an image file inside the file, wouldn't this still attempt to find `@web/themes/current/images/myImage.jpg` rather than `@web/themes/default/images/myImage.jpg`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, `basePath` is worthless. Because `basePath` is only applied when 
`pathMap` is empty.
`basePath` is not a fallback, It is a shortcut of `pathMap`, quick use when you only have one theme.

```
'pathMap' => [
    '@app/views' => [
         '@app/themes/current/views',
    ],
],
```

Equivalent to:

```
'basePath' => '@app/themes/current',
```

*(Yii understands that folder `@app/themes/current/views` exist)*
`baseUrl`: It is returned when you call `$this->theme->getBaseUrl()` in view file. Less worth with multi theme.
About fallback for static files. Theming fallback is not designed for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't need a *fallback* for the resources really, but preferably a way for it to take the resource from the same themes web accessible directory that it found the theme view file within the themes `@app` theme directory.

Comment: You can refer `applyTo()` function. But it works with file path: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-theme.html#applyTo()-detail

Comment: Then you wouldn't get theme fallback?

Answer (score 2):

Point your links inside file like this exmaple from [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-theming.html):

```
$theme = $this->theme;

// returns: $theme->baseUrl . '/img/logo.gif'
$url = $theme->getUrl('img/logo.gif');

// returns: $theme->basePath . '/img/logo.gif'
$file = $theme->getPath('img/logo.gif');
```

It will get file from current theme directory.

Comment: Thanks, but I already knew how to do that. That doesn't really explain what my question was asking.

Comment: If foo.php was found in `default` theme it will consider $this->theme->baseUrl and ->basePath belongs to `default` theme and it wouldn't search another themes to setup new base* values. @Brett